# Apache2 blocking access to specific directory in root of server

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403, apache-config

I'm working on setting up a website and at first I thought the website was broken but then I look and I'm getting 403d on everything under /javascript/

I've double checked the filesystem permissions. I can rename the javascript folder to js and access the files just fine from a browser. I've tried finding all the locations where the site tries to access /javascript/ and change it to just /js/ but there are some other scripts running that are generating some script tags and it's not proving easy to find them all.

My question is, is there an easy(ish) way to find where apache may be hanging me up? It's a basic apache2 install on ubuntu 14.04 running in a digital ocean droplet.

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel silly.

Just ran `grep -r "javascript" .` just the same as I was using it to look for references in the website and I see there's a default aliasing of /javascript in the apache2 conf of javascript-common (though it didn't seem to show up in conf-enabled). I ran `sudo a2disconf javascript-common` and I had access back to the folder.